# Windows 7 displays an NTFS formatted(under Windows 10) HDD as RAW partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partitioning, ntfs

I have a new HDD(ST2000DM009) which I formatted under Windows 10 as an NTFS MBR disk and copied some files on it. It's meant to be a storage HDD, not system one. When I connect this HDD to a Windows 7 x64 PC, Windows 7 tries to run chkdsk on it during system boot. I canceled it and now inside the Windows this disk is displayed as RAW partition.

I've connected this disk back to Windows 10 PC and all the files are there and all works fine.

How can I make this HDD work in Windows 7? Is this a driver issue or are Windows 10 NTFS incompatible with Windows 7's one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partition Wizard to recover your HDD data.
This software have actually many options to repair and recover your lost partitions. You need to recover your partition from the options displayed in the tool.

Details are here: You can make your HDD accessible by using the method given here.
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/convert-raw-to-ntfs.html

Comment: Welcome on Superuser, my suggestion is that your answer must include  more KEY information to fix the issue. Please refer this link, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: I am updating the Answer with more details. @RajeshS

Comment: What did you update in the answer @RajeshS?